# Как создать четырехугольник с разным расположением точек

Tags: css

Вот такой эффект должен быть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видно что четырехугольники имеют точки расположенные в разных местах, возможно ли это сделать с помощью css трансформаций? Или только svg?

```css
.block {

background:#fa0;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: если забить на IE и EDGE то вполне можно через clip-path. Можно в принципе и стандартными средствами CSS только чуть более выпендревшись

Comment: orangina.ru самое интересное сайт работает и в edge

Comment: .....так, и что?

Comment: есть такая штука http://www.useragentman.com/matrix/